# Compiling boost from source in Oracle Linux fails

Tags: boost

I am trying to compile boost libraries from source for Orcle Linux. However, the very first command `./bootstrap.sh` fails with the error

```
###
### Using 'gcc' toolset.
###
rm -rf bootstrap
mkdir bootstrap
gcc -o bootstrap/jam0 command.c compile.c constants.c debug.c execcmd.c frames.c function.c glob.c hash.c hdrmacro.c headers.c jam.
c jambase.c jamgram.c lists.c make.c make1.c object.c option.c output.c parse.c pathsys.c regexp.c rules.c scan.c search.c subst.c 
timestamp.c variable.c modules.c strings.c filesys.c builtins.c class.c cwd.c native.c md5.c w32_getreg.c modules/set.c modules/pat
h.c modules/regex.c modules/property-set.c modules/sequence.c modules/order.c execunix.c fileunix.c pathunix.c
./bootstrap/jam0 -f build.jam --toolset=gcc --toolset-root= clean
...found 1 target...
...updating 1 target...
[DELETE] clean
...updated 1 target...
./bootstrap/jam0 -f build.jam --toolset=gcc --toolset-root=
...found 158 targets...
...updating 2 targets...
[COMPILE] bin.linuxx86_64/b2
[COPY] bin.linuxx86_64/bjam
cp: preserving permissions for `bin.linuxx86_64/bjam': Operation not supported

        cp -Rpf "bin.linuxx86_64/b2" "bin.linuxx86_64/bjam"

...failed [COPY] bin.linuxx86_64/bjam...
...failed updating 1 target...
...updated 1 target...
```

I thought there might be an issue with where the files are being copied so did `./bootstrap.sh --prefix=./` Even that didn't work. I can try removing -p but I think there's a reason they included that. What could be the error? Also, is there a way to download latest boost libraries for Oracle Linux directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally ran it removing -p from build.jam file in tools/build/src/engine/build.jam subfolder. Worked fine and no errors. I am still wondering about the reason of -p though.

Comment: I'm having this very problem except on Ubuntu. Can you be more specific about which -p you removed? There are many. Was it the "p" from the cp command at line 986 of build.jam?

Comment: And preferably why?

Comment: Ah, it's been a long time so I dont remember. But it's this one 
 

cp -R'p'f "bin.linuxx86_64/b2" "bin.linuxx86_64/bjam"